# Showing $\pi_1(X\times Y) = \pi_1(X)\times\pi_1(Y)$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I wanted to show my proof of the statement included in the title. It went all too easy and I'm not sure if I hadn't forgotten about sth.

So, let $p_1:X\times Y\rightarrow X,\ p_2:X\times Y\rightarrow Y$ - projections. Then let $f:\pi_1(X\times Y) \longrightarrow \pi_1(X)\times\pi_1(Y)$ and $g:\pi_1(X)\times\pi_1(Y)\longrightarrow \pi_1(X\times Y)$. To prove the statement we set $$f(\omega)=(p_1\circ\omega,p_2\circ\omega)$$
$$g(\omega_1,\omega_2)=\overline{\omega}, $$ where $\forall t\in I,\ \  \overline{\omega}(t)=(\omega_1(t),\omega_2(t))$.

Then $f\circ g= id$ and $g\circ f = id$ and both functions are well-defined which finishes the proof.

Is it ok?

Comment: I think its close, but you should probably be aware that elements of $\pi_1(X)$ aren't loops, as such: they are an *equivalence class* of loops. So, say, for $f$ you are given an equivalence class $[\omega]$ and you define $f([\omega]) = [p_1\circ \omega]\times [p_2 \circ \omega]$, you want to make sure it is clear that this is well defined on the equivalence classes.

Comment: What exactly does $\pi_1 (X \times Y)$ and $\pi_1( X)$ mean?

Comment: @AbhishekBhat This is standard notation for the *fundamental group* (of $X\times Y$ and $X$, respectively).

Comment: @James: Thank you for pointing that out, I somehow missed it.